# How to add new input in register page laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to add a new field on Laravel's register page that's store the new
data in my database.
still learning Laravel so basically, i am a newbie.
I need help on this, Thank you

Comment: You should really start from reading [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/l) or watching [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/).

Comment: Basically add your input filed in blade file and pick it in controller like other fields...

Answer (score 2):

It is simple as adding a new field in database and form. Go through the basic documentation of Laravel before jumping into it.

Basically, follow these steps:

1) Add a new column to your database table (ie: 'users' table)

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `address` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `name`;
```

*(This is just a raw format to add the field for a basic user, Best way to add field is to use [laravel migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations))*

2) Add an input field to registration form page (`register.blade.php`)

```
<input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required>
```

3) Make change on your `RegisterController.php`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a migration to add the new field instead of a raw query.

Comment: Agreed, that is the best way, editing my answer with the note for that , thank you mate