# Laravel 7 query builder ignoring new data

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I was trying to create new input to default registration form (This is similar [How to add new input in register page laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051425/how-to-add-new-input-in-register-page-laravel/48052864)). But SQL command created by code below don't add my new data in command.

```php
protected function create(array $data) 
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);
}
```

In SQL i get something like `INSERT INTO "user" ("name","email","password") VALUES ...` and adress is ignored.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you set `$fillable` on the model to accept this new field that you are mass assigning? and this is Eloquent, not Query Builder

Comment: As @lagbox said, you are using Eloquent,  so you need to add this `address` column in **User** model `$fillable`

Answer (score 0):

Add fillable property in User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'address'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
}
```